# Is there a way to setup a shortcut to "re-run" the Delphi LSP instances?

Tags: delphi, language-server-protocol

As long as the Delphi LSP implementation has its flaws, it would come in handy if we could restart the LSP processes with an easy to reach shortcut. How can such a shortcut be added?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Under *Tools - Configure Tools* add a new entry named *Kill LSP* with the following settings:

```
Program: taskkill
Parameters: /IM DelphiLSP.exe /F
```

This will add a new menu entry *Kill LSP* under the *Tools* menu.